# DosBox 0.74 - "Illegal Command" Error When Mounting

Tags: dosbox

I am running DosBox 0.74 on Linux Mint 18 and have an issue with trying to run certain built-in commands.

When using the `dosbox-0.74.conf` file to mount images, folder, etc., it works fine. However, I am unable to mount anything from within the DosBox prompt itself.

When trying to use the `mount` or `imgmount` commands, I get the error `Illegal command: mount.`.

Even running `help /all` does not list these as available commands.

I seem to remember being able to use `mount` all the time in the past (and indeed, **many** tutorials found online still say to issue the `mount` command from within DosBox).

What am I missing?

Comment: Incidentally, I removed all my `mount` commands from the `.conf` file and I was able to issue `mount` commands within DosBox again. Does DOSBox only allow mounting in one place or the other?

Comment: What EXACTLY is the mount command you're trying to use, and what EXACTLY is the error you get. I set my path to null: "Z:\>path=", and ask dosbox what my path is: "Z:\>path" --> "PATH=(null)", and dosbox can still find the "mount" command. But if you unset Z, and switch to a different drive/directory, you'll get that exact error. At the dosbox prompt, enter "path=z:\". Then check if you can use mount.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about general computing, not gaming (I don't think DOSBox counts as gaming-specific software)

Comment: We do have a 'dosbox' tag, and its description reads that it is "primarily intended for playing older games".

Comment: A bit unsure of this one. While dosbox's own website say it's primarily for games, I know you can do more with it. I've personally compiled the C code for Wolfenstein 3D using it and played it.  I guess you can say that's somewhat gaming related too though? :)

Comment: All of you are making several valid points. I'll just let the close vote review queue decide whether DOSBox counts as gaming-specific or not (I, as a general rule, interpret the gaming-specific hardware and software prong more narrowly than most of the community)

Answer (score 2):

The `mount` and `imgmount` commands exist on the virtual Z: drive within DOSBox. You need to either keep `Z:\` in the `PATH` or specify the drive letter explicitly when running them. For example:

```
z:mount c c:\games
z:imgmount d c:\cdgame.iso -t iso
```

Answer (score -2):

Just restart Dosbox by rightclick on Dosbox and run as Administrator. Illegal command solved.